# Grails Ajax: Render Template not picking up parent resource(js)

Tags: ajax, grails

My Scenerios:

I am using grails remoteFunction which is rendering template. I have a slider on the render template which is using some Jquery methods. Previously I have kept js within this template but the problem is with performance. Everytime the ajax loads the jquery classes which is causing the performance issues.

Is there a way to get the parent resource by templates after rendering thru Ajax ?

Inside index.gsp page:

```
<g:if test="${action=="individual"}">
    <g:render template="individual" />
</g:if>
<g:if test="${action=="project"}">
    <g:render template="project" />
</g:if>

<asset:javascript src="bootstrap/jquery-1.10.2.js"></asset:javascript>
<asset:javascript src="bootstrap/bootstrap-slider.js"></asset:javascript>
<asset:javascript src="resource_utilization/slider.js"></asset:javascript>
<asset:javascript src="resource_utilization/resource-utilization.js"></asset:javascript>
<asset:javascript src="jquery.blockUI.js"></asset:javascript>
```

In controller:

```
render template:"individual"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read this [link](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Template-rendering-and-jQuery-DOM-question-td2534214.html). When you render template inside parent then your jquery will not work. For that to work you have to reactivate the js resource.

I have done the following. In parent gsp load all the resources and add one method to initialize your slider.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function refreshUI () {
            // your slider initialization code goes here

        };
    </script>
```

In template at the end just call the parent function.

```
<script>
refreshUI();
</script>
```

This will refresh your UI and everything will work fine.